# R from long to wide dataframe with real valued columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, reshape, tibble

I have a quick question that relates to reshaping my data frame where I have ID "grouped_by" data.
I have the following schema of the df (+ 2 exemplary instances that I wish to widen (in total I have >5000)):

```
   id                  solver   scoreA  scoreB  group   size 
   <chr>               <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 instance_1          s1       1        0.5    g1      1000                     
 2 instance_1          s2       100      50     g1      1000
```

... what I want to gain is:

```
   id           solver.best  scoreA.s1  scoreA.s2  scoreB.s1   scoreB.s2  group   size 
   <chr>        <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <chr>   <dbl>
 1 instance_1   s1           1          100        0.5         50         g1      1000
```

Appreciate your help.
BR

Comment: If you have over 5000 rows, and you want to do this - you will have around 5000 columns, this is almost surely the wrong way to go. What you are trying to accomplish should have an alternative route.

Comment: the ID is always grouping 2 instances... basically saying I want two rows becoming flat. i.e. groing from 5000 rows to 2500

Comment: You  can do the math, what's the difference between 5 x 5000 and 2500 x 5000 ?

Comment: I do not see your point. I admit that spreading via tidyverse techniques may not lead to the preferred result and with no grouping one will end up in 2500 x 5000 df. Other than that I dont see any fatality in the idea to shrink 2 rows into one once grouped by ID...

Comment: The purpose of asking you to share `dput` is that we can copy your data (or part of it) in our R environment and use it. When you update your post with incomplete `dput` (which we cannot copy) it's as good as not sharing at all. If your data is very big you can share only first few rows like `dput(head(df))` for first 6 rows.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that the data is confidential and it is not easy for me to pseudonyze/mask it. To be honest, I think that the schema gives the idea -- after id: instance_1 comes instance_2 --> again pairwise. All the way up until 10000, so we have 5000 unique IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
reshape(within(df, Q <- ave(seq(nrow(df)), id, FUN = seq_along)),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "id", 
  timevar = "Q"
)
```

which gives

```
> reshape(cbind(df,Q = seq(nrow(df))),direction = "wide",idvar = "id",timevar = "Q")
          id solver.1 scoreA.1 scoreB.1 group.1 size.1 solver.2 scoreA.2
1 instance 1       s1        1      0.5      g1   1000       s2      100
  scoreB.2 group.2 size.2
1       50      g1   1000
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c("instance 1", "instance 1"), solver = c("s1", 
"s2"), scoreA = c(1L, 100L), scoreB = c(0.5, 50), group = c("g1",
"g1"), size = c(1000L, 1000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2"))
```

Comment: thanks, but it only returns NA values for me :/....
I have more tham just 2 rows. But there are always 2 instances groubed_by ID...

Comment: @gero Did you use the data in my answer? Otherwise, please `dput()` your data then I will have a look what happened

Comment: structure(list(id = c("instance 1", 
"instance 1", "instance 2", 
"instance 2", [... more instances/groups ...],
 solver = c("S1", 
"S2", [... more solver ...], scoreA = c(3.3818, 
358.1937, ....,
 scoreB = c(1.3818, 
100.1937, ...., group = c("g1", 
"g1", ...., size = c("1000", "1000", ....)

Comment: @gero Could you put you data in your post? It seems the data you showed in the comment is not complete

Comment: The data is confidential. However, here is everything from dput() (find in edited post)

Answer (score 0):

As I still wish to have a handy, e.g. tidyverse, best-practice, I still want to share the practical approach, which works just as fine conceptually :):

```
# create empty (wide) target df
wide_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 0))

names <- c("id", "best_solver", "scoreA_s1", "scoreA_s2",
           "scoreB_s1", "scoreB_s2", "group", "size")
colnames(wide_df) <- names


# traverse grouped by and arranged original (long) df 
for(i in seq(2, length(long_df$group), by = 2)){
  wide_df[i/2, "id"] <- long_df[i, "id"]
  wide_df[i/2, "best_solver"] <- long_df[which(long_df[(i-1):i, "scoreA"] ==
                                 min(long_df[i-1, "scoreA"], long_df[i, "scoreA"])), 
                                 "solver"]
  wide_df[i/2, "scoreA_s1"] <- long_df[i-1, "scoreA"]
  wide_df[i/2, "scoreA_s2"] <- long_df[i, "scoreA"]
  wide_df[i/2, "scoreB_s1"] <- long_df[i-1, "scoreB"]
  wide_df[i/2, "scoreB_s2"] <- long_df[i, "scoreB"]
  wide_df[i/2, "group"] <- long_df[i, "group"]
  wide_df[i/2, "size"] <- long_df[i, "size"]
}
```